# How can i make responsive HTML Table with 90% width of screen

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, cover

Hello i have issue with table ive created table and at 1920*1080 24" monitor it looks very good. Issue is if user has smaller monitor like notebook, table, phone. Use must use horizontal scroller. How can i make responsiv table which will be always for example 90% of the screen width without horizontal scrolling?

Table what i have is here: https://natus.cz/tabulka/

Id like something like this. I mean right side.

https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/4/12/2b8c685ff1871d02b08a0bb0b3fdd50c-full.png.html

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width: 100%;max-width: 90vw;height: 1495px;">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="background-color: #c491ff;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #8cc6fe;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #59fe93;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #8cfd58;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #bffb91;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fdfdc9;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fdfb67;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fec800;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #ff9500;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #ff6401;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fe451c;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fd451c;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fb0303;" span="1">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 48px;">
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 44.02%;" colspan="2">
                    SILNĚ ZÁSADOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 144.255%;" colspan="4">
                    MÍRNĚ ZÁSADOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 7.68673%;">
                    NEUTRÁLNÍ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 30.76%;" colspan="4">
                    MÍRNĚ KYSELINOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 15.38%;" colspan="2">
                    SILNĚ KYSELINOTVORNÉ
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="" style="height: 24px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 9</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 29.76%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8.5 – 8</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 32.5003%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8 – 7.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 0.725163%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7.5 – 7</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6.5 – 6</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 5.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>&nbsp;pH 5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 5 – 4</strong></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 24px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 24px;">
                    Relaxace
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 24px;">
                    Asparagus
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 24px;">
                    Jablka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 24px;">
                    Červená řepa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 24px;">
                    Okurka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 24px;">
                    Amarant
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 24px;">
                    Syrové mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Špalda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Čočka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Pohanka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Mořské plody
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Kuřecí maso
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Hověží maso
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 72px;">
                    Oddych
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Čekanka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Meruňky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 72px;">
                    Papriky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 72px;">
                    Artičoky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 72px;">
                    Jáhly
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 72px;">
                    Oleje bio kvalita(kromě olyvového)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Brazilské ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Ječmen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Rýžové chlebíčky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Ryby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Krůtí maso
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Vepřové
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 61px;">
                    Meditace
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 61px;">
                    Ovocné zeleninové šťávy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 61px;">
                    Avokádo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 61px;">
                    Brokolice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 61px;">
                    Lilek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 61px;">
                    Quinoa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 61px;">
                    Neslazený jogurt
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Pekanové ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Makadamové ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Celozrnné krekry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Víno
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Zvěřina
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Telecí
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 10px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 10px;">
                    Laskavost
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 10px;">
                    Bylinný čaj
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 10px;">
                    Banány
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 10px;">
                    Květák
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 10px;">
                    Pór
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 10px;">
                    Rebarbora
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 10px;">
                    Syrovátka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Pistácie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Kešu
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Celozrnné cereálie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Syrupy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Zajíc
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Bílý cukr
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 72px;">
                    Láska
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Umeboshi
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Dýně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 72px;">
                    Zelí
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 72px;">
                    Třešně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 72px;">
                    Rajčata
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 72px;">
                    Smetana
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Vaječný bílek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Pasterizované mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Domácí celozrnný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Konzervy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Marmeláda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Bílá mouka
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Mladý ječmen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Rozinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Maliny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Kapusta
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Višně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Ředkvička
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;">
                    Bio máslo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Cottage cheese
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Mléčné výrobky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže červená
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Zavařeniny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Hnědý cukr
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bílý chléb a pečivo
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Citron
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Hrušky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Rybíz
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Pastinák
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Kaštany
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Křen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Měkké sýry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Jahodový syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže hnědá
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Oslazené cereálie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Čokoláda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Koláče
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 64px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 64px;">
                    Červený meloun
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 64px;">
                    Kiwi
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 64px;">
                    Ostružiny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 64px;">
                    Kedlubna
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 64px;">
                    Okra
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 64px;">
                    Sojové boby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 64px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Zavařené olivy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Javorový syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Pšenice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Müsli a tyčinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Těstoviny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Dorty
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Petržel
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Ananas
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvé datle
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Tuřín
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Rajčata
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Sojové mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Fazole
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Ječný syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Ovesné vločky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničné klíčky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Cigarety
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Stévie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvé fíky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Kukuřice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Houby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Bio sojové produkty
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušené švestky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Med
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Tvrdé sýry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Celozrnný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Krupice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Uzeniny
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Řasa agar
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Chlorela
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Grapefruit
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Tykev
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Cibule
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Tofu
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Borůvky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Fruktóza
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Tvaroh
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sladká šlehačka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Masové výrobky
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Cantaloupe
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Spirulina
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Guava
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Brambory se slupkou
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvý kokos
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Tempeh
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušený kokos
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Melasa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bryndza
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slazené džusy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničné pečivo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Coca Cola
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Chilli
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Syrový hráškový protein
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Kaki
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Mladé fazolky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Syrový med
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Nutriční droždí
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Brusinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Hořčice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Kečup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slazené jogurty
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bonbóny
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    <strong>pH 4</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušené datle
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Makové mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Broskve
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Kakaové boby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Růžičková kapusta
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Syrové kozí mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Lněné semínky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Muškátový ořech
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Majonéza
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Tvarohové jogurty
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slazené nápoje
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Umělé sladidla
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušené fíky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Mladý hrášek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Nektarinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Sladké brambory
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvé olivy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Olivový olej
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pasterizované kozí mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Otruby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sójová omáčka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Oslezená mléka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Energy drinky
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Přepracování
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Chaluha
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Mateřské mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Česnek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Karobový prášek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Tamari
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Lněný olej
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Ochucené máslo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Neochucený popcorn
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Brambory
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Domácí tabák
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Kafe
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Hněv
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Limetka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Persimon
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Salát
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Aloe Vera
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Kakaový prášek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Mandle
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Žito
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Chléb s klíčkami
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Černý čaj
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Žárlivost
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Papája
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Angrešt
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Špenát
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Jahody
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Miso
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Lískové ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Žitný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Alkohol
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Strach
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Petržel
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    List. zelen.
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Pomeranč
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Taro
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Sezam
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slunečnicové semínka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pivo
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Chronický stres
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Mořské řasy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Mrkev
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Zázvor
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýžový ocet
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Baklažán
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Dýňové semínka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bílý ocet
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Chřest
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Celer
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Jablečný ocet
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Bylinkové koření
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Kaštany
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Stolní sůl
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Hrozno
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Kokosový olej
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Klíčky zrní
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you get a working answer on this ?

Answer (score 0):

give fixed width property to  you're body element for example :

```
body{
 width:1920px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to set all tr td widths according to 100%. like if you want 5 parts of a table so you divided 100 into 5 parts is it odd or even. As I see you didn't follow that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add:

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

This way the table will accept your width set. Here the width applied are those in your `th` this is why it seems not equal.

### DEMO (reduced `tr` line compared to original because of limited lines).

```css
table{
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table style="width: 100%;max-width: 90vw;height: 1495px;">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="background-color: #c491ff;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #8cc6fe;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #59fe93;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #8cfd58;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #bffb91;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fdfdc9;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fdfb67;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fec800;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #ff9500;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #ff6401;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fe451c;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fd451c;" span="1">
            <col style="background-color: #fb0303;" span="1">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height: 48px;">
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 44.02%;" colspan="2">
                    SILNĚ ZÁSADOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 144.255%;" colspan="4">
                    MÍRNĚ ZÁSADOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 7.68673%;">
                    NEUTRÁLNÍ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 30.76%;" colspan="4">
                    MÍRNĚ KYSELINOTVORNÉ
                </th>
                <th style="height: 48px; width: 15.38%;" colspan="2">
                    SILNĚ KYSELINOTVORNÉ
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="" style="height: 24px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 9</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 29.76%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8.5 – 8</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 32.5003%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8 – 7.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 0.725163%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7.5 – 7</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 7</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6.5 – 6</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 6</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 5.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>&nbsp;pH 5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td class="no-pading" style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 5 – 4</strong></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 24px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 24px;">
                    Relaxace
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 24px;">
                    Asparagus
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 24px;">
                    Jablka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 24px;">
                    Červená řepa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 24px;">
                    Okurka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 24px;">
                    Amarant
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 24px;">
                    Syrové mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Špalda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Čočka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Pohanka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Mořské plody
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Kuřecí maso
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 24px;">
                    Hověží maso
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 72px;">
                    Oddych
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Čekanka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Meruňky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 72px;">
                    Papriky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 72px;">
                    Artičoky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 72px;">
                    Jáhly
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 72px;">
                    Oleje bio kvalita(kromě olyvového)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Brazilské ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Ječmen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Rýžové chlebíčky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Ryby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Krůtí maso
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Vepřové
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 61px;">
                    Meditace
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 61px;">
                    Ovocné zeleninové šťávy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 61px;">
                    Avokádo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 61px;">
                    Brokolice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 61px;">
                    Lilek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 61px;">
                    Quinoa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 61px;">
                    Neslazený jogurt
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Pekanové ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Makadamové ořechy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Celozrnné krekry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Víno
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Zvěřina
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 61px;">
                    Telecí
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 10px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 10px;">
                    Laskavost
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 10px;">
                    Bylinný čaj
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 10px;">
                    Banány
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 10px;">
                    Květák
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 10px;">
                    Pór
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 10px;">
                    Rebarbora
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 10px;">
                    Syrovátka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Pistácie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Kešu
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Celozrnné cereálie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Syrupy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Zajíc
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 10px;">
                    Bílý cukr
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 72px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 72px;">
                    Láska
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Umeboshi
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 72px;">
                    Dýně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 72px;">
                    Zelí
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 72px;">
                    Třešně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 72px;">
                    Rajčata
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 72px;">
                    Smetana
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Vaječný bílek
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Pasterizované mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Domácí celozrnný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Konzervy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Marmeláda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 72px;">
                    Bílá mouka
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Mladý ječmen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Rozinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Maliny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Kapusta
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Višně
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Ředkvička
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;">
                    Bio máslo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Cottage cheese
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Mléčné výrobky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže červená
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Zavařeniny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Hnědý cukr
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bílý chléb a pečivo
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Citron
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Hrušky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Rybíz
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Pastinák
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Kaštany
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Křen
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Měkké sýry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Jahodový syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže hnědá
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Oslazené cereálie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Čokoláda
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Koláče
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 64px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 64px;">
                    Červený meloun
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 64px;">
                    Kiwi
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 64px;">
                    Ostružiny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 64px;">
                    Kedlubna
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 64px;">
                    Okra
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 64px;">
                    Sojové boby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 64px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Zavařené olivy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Javorový syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Pšenice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Müsli a tyčinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Těstoviny
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 64px;">
                    Dorty
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Petržel
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Ananas
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvé datle
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Tuřín
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Rajčata
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Sojové mléko
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Fazole
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Ječný syrup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Ovesné vločky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničné klíčky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Rýže
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Cigarety
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 14pt;"><strong>pH 8.5</strong></span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Stévie
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvé fíky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Kukuřice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Houby
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Bio sojové produkty
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušené švestky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Med
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Tvrdé sýry
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Celozrnný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Krupice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Uzeniny
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Řasa agar
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Chlorela
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Grapefruit
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Tykev
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Cibule
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Tofu
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Borůvky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Fruktóza
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Tvaroh
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sladká šlehačka
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničný chléb
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Masové výrobky
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Cantaloupe
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Spirulina
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Guava
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Brambory se slupkou
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Čerstvý kokos
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Tempeh
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Sušený kokos
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Melasa
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bryndza
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slazené džusy
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Pšeničné pečivo
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Coca Cola
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 56px;">
                <td class="second_half1" style="width: 14.26%; height: 56px;">
                    Chilli
                </td>
                <td style="width: 29.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Syrový hráškový protein
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.76%; height: 56px;">
                    Kaki
                </td>
                <td style="width: 32.5003%; height: 56px;">
                    Mladé fazolky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 103.27%; height: 56px;">
                    Syrový med
                </td>
                <td style="width: 0.725163%; height: 56px;">
                    Nutriční droždí
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.68673%; height: 56px;"></td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Brusinky
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Hořčice
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Kečup
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Slazené jogurty
                </td>
                <td style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    Bonbóny
                </td>
                <td class="second_half2" style="width: 7.69%; height: 56px;">
                    <strong>pH 4</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```